# Increasing iOS app version and build numbers?

Tags: ios, version

This is a very noobie question, but I can't seem to find any specifics on it from searches.

For my iOS app, do I manually increase the version and build numbers myself from the "General" tab in xcode, or is it done through the code signing or what?

Updating it myself seems simple, but I feel like maybe thats not what I'm supposed to be doing.

Thanks

Comment: you can increase version using xcode general tab and .plist file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign manually from Xcode itself and even if you want it automatically then also it is possible

This numbers are just for unique identification on app store, so every time you need to change the version number from previous one

You can go through this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

For automatic increment use agvtool 
visit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html